# Using python and regex to find stings and put them together to replace the filename of a .pdf- the rename fails when using more than one group

Tags: python, regex, pdf, rename

I have several thousand pdfs which I need to re-name based on the content.  The layouts of the pdfs are inconsistent.  To re-name them I need to locate a specific string "MEMBER".  I need the value after the string "MEMBER" and the values from the two lines above MEMBER, which are Time and Date values respectively.

So:
STUFF
STUFF
STUFF
DD/MM/YY
HH:MM:SS
MEMBER ######
STUFF
STUFF
STUFF

I have been using regex101.com and have ((.*(\n|\r|\r\n)){2})(MEMBER.\S+) which matches all of the values I need.  But it puts them across four groups with group 3 just showing a carriage return.

What I have so far looks like this:

```
import fitz
from os import DirEntry, curdir, chdir, getcwd, rename
from glob import glob as glob
import re

failed_pdfs = []
count = 0
pdf_regex = r'((.*(\n|\r|\r\n)){2})(MEMBER.\S+)'
text = ""
get_curr = getcwd()
directory = 'PDF_FILES'
chdir(directory)

pdf_list = glob('*.pdf')

for pdf in pdf_list:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as pdf_obj:
        for page in pdf_obj:
            text += page.get_text()
    new_file_name = re.search(pdf_regex, text).group().strip().replace(":","").replace("-","") + '.pdf'
    text = ""
    #clean_new_file_name = new_file_name.translate({(":"): None})
    print(new_file_name)
    # Tries to rename a pdf. If the filename doesn't already exist
    # then rename. If it does exist then throw an error and add to failed list
    try:
        rename(pdf, new_file_name )
    except WindowsError:
        count += 1
        failed_pdfs.append(str(count) + ' - FAILED TO RENAME: [' + pdf + " ----> " + str(new_file_name) + "]")
```

If I specify a group in the re.search portion- Like for instance Group 4 which contains the MEMBER ##### value, then the file renames successfully with just that value.  Similarly, Group 2 renames with the TIME value.  I think the multiple lines are preventing it from using all of the values I need.  When I run it with group(), the print value shows as
DATE
TIME
MEMBER ######.pdf

And the log count reflects the failures.

I am very new at this, and stumbling around trying to piece together how things work.  Is the issue with how I built the regex or with the re.search portion?  Or everything?

I have tried re-doing the Regular Expression, but I end up with multiple lines in the results, which seems connected to the rename failure.

Comment: you can use `?:` to stop it from capturing a particular grouping. Something like this: `r'((?:.*(?:\n|\r|\r\n)){2})(MEMBER.\S+)'` (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-17)

Comment: The three lines containing the date, time and "MEMBER ######" strings: are they consecutive and each of them the only things in their lines? If yes, then you do not need regular expressions at all. If you can confirm, I could sketch a code doing this.

Comment: @JorjMcKie Yes.  They are on their own lines and always in the consecutive order: Date, Time, and then Member #####  The placement within the body of the pdf varies significantly, as does the length of the Member value.

Comment: @Zippa - great, thanks. Please look at my suggestion below.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is to read the page's text by words and sort them adequately.
If we then find "MEMBER", the word following it represents the hashes ####, and the two preceeding words must be date and time respectively.

```py
found = False
for page in pdf_obj:
    words = page.get_text("words", sort=True)
    # all space-delimited strings on the page, sorted vertically,
    # then horizontally
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word[4] == "MEMBER":
            hashes = words[i+1][4]  # this must be the word after MEMBER!
            time-string = words[i-1][4]  # the time
            date_string = words[i-2][4]  # the date
            found = True
            break
    if found == True:  # no need to look in other pages
        break
```